# Filtering 2 array composite object elements using java 8 stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 array objects, the first one is composite and another one is a simple array of object, based upon some comparison if match found, create a new list. That would be a filtered list based upon conditions. I did that using java `1.7` version, however looking for guidance if this can be achievable with less code using `java-8`.

Here is my code which creates a new list based upon a conditional filter

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    String[] accountOid = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
    AccountHoldCompositeObj[] accts = prepare();
    ArrayList<AccountHoldCompositeObj> list = new ArrayList<AccountHoldCompositeObj>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < accountOid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < accts.length; j++) {
            ObjectId oid =  new ObjectId(accountOid[i]);
            if (oid.equals(accts[j].getAccountOid())) {
                AccountHoldCompositeObj anAccount = (AccountHoldCompositeObj) accts[j].clone();                 
                list.add(anAccount);
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    list.stream().forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
}

private static AccountHoldCompositeObj[] prepare() {
    AccountHoldCompositeObj[] valArr = new AccountHoldCompositeObj[5];
    int k =10;
    for (int i=0;i<50;i++){         
        AccountHoldCompositeObj create = new AccountHoldCompositeObj(); 
        create.setAccountId(Integer.toString(k));//some more elements
        create.setAccountOid(new ObjectId(i)); 
        valArr[i] = create;
        k++;
    }
    return valArr;
}
```

I tried to convert array in stream and then used filter, but somehow not able to compare exactly 2 different elements, that is :

1. `accountOid[i]` of `accountOid` array (simple array)
2. `accts[j].getAccountOid()` of `AccountHoldCompisiteObj` array (composite
   array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your goal is to transform the inner `for-loop` with the outer one. Practically, all you do is a comparison of the `ObjectId` object received from each of `AccountHoldCompositeObject` with a group of predefined `String` OIDs as a template for the `ObjectId` to be compared. The `.clone()` is not needed.

Before entering Stream I recommend prepare data first for the fluent and easy manipulation and usage. The last you want is to perform the complicated transformation inside a lambda. Do:

1. Define a set `Set<ObjectId>` of the transformed OIDs (`String` to `ObjectId`).
2. Iterate the list and search ones with OID available in the predefined `Set<ObjectId>`.
3. Collect the remaining to a desired output.

Here you go:

```
Set<ObjectId> idSet = Arrays.stream(accountOid)             // Stream over String[]
                            .map(str -> new ObjectId(str))  // Create ObjectId from each
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());   // Collect to Set<ObjectId>

List<AccountHoldCompositeObj> list = Arrays
    .stream(accts)                                          // Stream over AccountHoldCompositeObj[]
    .filter(acct -> idSet.contains(acct.getAccountOid()))   // Filter elements by IDs
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                          // Collect to List
```

Answer (score 2):

There is lots of for loop , I added new code like below. I commented out some lines to understand whats going on there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<AccountHoldCompositeObj> accts = prepare();
        Set<ObjectId> setOfAccountObjectId = IntStream.range(1, 8) //Int stream range between 1-8
                .map(str -> new ObjectId(str)) // Create ObjectId
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Collect into Set

        accts.stream()                                          // Stream for AccountHoldComposite array
                .filter(acct -> setOfAccountObjectId.contains(acct.getAccountOid()))   // Filter elements by existing ids
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<AccountHoldCompositeObj> prepare() {
        int k = 10;
        //creating AccountHoldCompositeObj elements between 0-50
        return Stream.iterate(0, m -> m + 1)
                .limit(50)
                .map(currentId -> {
                    AccountHoldCompositeObj create = new AccountHoldCompositeObj();
                    create.setAccountId(Integer.toString(k));//some more elements
                    create.setAccountOid(new ObjectId(currentId));
                    return create;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Edit : I added `Stream.iterate` for your `for loop` which is between `0 and 50`.

Comment: prepare() method is giving me error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from AccountHoldCompositeObj to int"

Comment: .map(str->new ObjectId(str)) is giving me error ".collect(Collectors.toSet());" Am I making any mistake, I copied the given code

Comment: ObjectId is your own class or not ?

Comment: Yes, ObjectId is my custom class. This edit made it work, by using Stream.iterate and list as return type to prepare method. Thanks !

Comment: While filtering accts.stream().... if I want to set some more properties based upon the filter, I used peek method then collecting the list, using peek is fine ? as this is used mainly for debug ?

Comment: If you wants more properties to filter , you can bind with and operator && or others. filter needs a return value as true or false. You can write method as well to control more data.